# Remove the navigation drawer icon and use the app icon to open

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I want to remove the small navigation drawer icon and open the left panel on actionbar icon click. How can I do this?

Actually I'm creating an Actionbar like Pinterest's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the `DrawerLayout` indicator don't use the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. To toggle the `DrawerLayout` when you select the `ActionBar` home affordance call `DrawerLayout.openDrawer` and `DrawerLayout.closeDrawer` depending on the current state.

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerVisible(GravityCompat.START)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Also, from what I can tell Pinterest doesn't use a `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: It's not that it uses navigation drawer, it's just kind of the same look and feel that I need. But your code already helped me. Thanks.