# Android menu item with icon and text on this icon

Tags: android, menu

I need to make "a shopping cart icon in action bar like in attached image 
with text on icon with count of items which user added to cart"

[image: Image show icon with text on it]

Comment: Do you have any question?

Comment: Have you attempt or try anything ?

Comment: someone give me this link 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009812/how-to-add-badges-on-toolbar-menuitem-icons?fref=gc

its solved my problem at all

Answer (score 0):

Given the conditions of the feature I believe you need to implement something something like the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/heart_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/number_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

okey then you need to create your icon menu bar manually to have full control on it.

firstly in **activity.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"                
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
            <!-- set any fixed size for 'width' but DO NOT set wrap_content-->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="[YOUR ICON]"/>
                <!-- you can set any attributes you want (background-fixed position .. etc) 
                     and you can also remove alignParentBottom , alignParentEnd .. 
                     i just add it to be clear -->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/notification_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

then you can access to them directly if you use activity .. if you use fragment then do these steps.

in **Fragment Class** : add setter for both image_icon and text_notification

```
private ImageView iconImageView;
private TextView textNotificationView;


public void setIconImageView(ImageView iconImageView){
    this.iconImageView= iconImageView;
}
public void setTextNotificationView(TextView textNotificationView){
    this.textNotificationView= textNotificationView;
}
```

then you need to set your fragment manually. 
In **Activity Class**

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) { // for rotation
        [FragmentClass] fragment = new [FragmentClass]();
        fragment.setIconImageView( (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.child_list_search_edit_view))
        fragment.setTextNotificationView( (TextView)findViewById(notification_text_view))

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment, fragment, [Fragment TAG]).commit();
    }else{

        [FragmentClass] childActivityFragment =([FragmentClass]) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag([Fragment TAG]);

        fragment.setIconImageView( (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.child_list_search_edit_view))
        fragment.setTextNotificationView( (TextView)findViewById(notification_text_view))

    }
```

Now you can add your notifications as you want.

Comment: Thanks , i have tried this solution and works good for me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35009812/how-to-add-badges-on-toolbar-menuitem-icons?fref=gc